# Code For Sharing Site Content on Social Networks

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I have a website with articles listed on a blog page and I want to have a custom Facebook Share, Tweet This & Email link assigned for each article.  Here is the code for the Twitter link:

```
<a href=\"https://twitter.com/share\" data-url=\"http://www.mywebsite.co.uk?article=$article_id\"><div class=\"shareCell shareTwitter\"></div></a>
```

The problem is that when I click on the tweet image it tries to share the main blog page rather than the relative article - Any ideas why or how to sort it.

Also, how can the same be done for Facebook and Emailing the article direct?

Answer (score 0):

You have escaped the whole html, I suspect that you use php.

```
<a href=\"https://twitter.com/share\" data-url=\"http://www.mywebsite.co.uk?article=$article_id\"><div class=\"shareCell shareTwitter\"></div></a>
```

should be:

```
<a href=\"https://twitter.com/share\" data-url=\"http://www.mywebsite.co.uk?article=" . $article_id . "\"><div class=\"shareCell shareTwitter\"></div></a>
```

$article_id is a variable from php

for facebook there is a very similar approach here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

and for sending emails:

```
<a href="mailto:emailname@yourdomain.com?subject=encodeURIComponent('Check out the blogpost http://www.mywebsite.co.uk?article=" . $article_id . "');">Send in email</a>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is still showing the url for the main page (http://www.mysite.co.uk/blog.php) and not the article (http://www.mysite.co.uk/article.php?article=1)

Comment: Then there seems to be something else that is the problem in your code. Because if article.php redirects you to blog.php there has to be some error handling in the code that does it, or a url rewrite filter or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
function fb_share(url)
{
var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' +encodeURIComponent('<?php echo full_path();?>'+url);
window.open(url, 'Share on FaceBook', 'left=20,top=20,width=550,height=400,toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,resizable=1');
return false;
}
</script>
```

```html
//first upon put this given below php code in ur header or top of the page.

<?php
function full_path()
{
    $s = &$_SERVER;
    $ssl = (!empty($s['HTTPS']) && $s['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? true:false;
    $sp = strtolower($s['SERVER_PROTOCOL']);
    $protocol = substr($sp, 0, strpos($sp, '/')) . (($ssl) ? 's' : '');
    $port = $s['SERVER_PORT'];
    $port = ((!$ssl && $port=='80') || ($ssl && $port=='443')) ? '' : ':'.$port;
    $host = isset($s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']) ? $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] : (isset($s['HTTP_HOST']) ? $s['HTTP_HOST'] : null);
    $host = isset($host) ? $host : $s['SERVER_NAME'] . $port;
    $uri = $protocol . '://' . $host . $s['REQUEST_URI'];
    $segments = explode('?', $uri, 2);
    $url = $segments[0];
    return $url;
}

?>

// This is the part of HTML Portion that you need to be included in your article section

<a href="javascript:fb_share('?article=1')">Share this on Facebook</a>
```